# How to model a set of unique objects?

Tags: database-design, erd, many-to-many

I have an entity type called 'Object', and I need to model an object set as a list of unique objects with variable length. Then, each object could belongs to many object sets.

**Current entity-relationship diagram (ERD)**

This is my ERD so far, with a many-to-many relationship:

[image]

**Tables design**

At this point, we have the next tables:

Object table:

- ObjectID (PrimaryKey)
- ObjectAttribute1
- ObjectAttribute2
- [...]

ObjectSet table:

- ObjectSetID (PrimaryKey)
- ObjectSetAttribute1
- [...]

ObjectBelongsObjectSet:

- ObjectSetID (ForeignKey)
- ObjectID (ForeignKey)

Using this model, we could have two different sets of objects with exactly the same combination of objects, which could never happen.

**My question**

How could improve my model to implement this restriction?

Comment: In that case the 'set of Objects' is an unique attribute of the ObjectSet, not a relation.

Comment: as a multievaluated attribute of foreign keys? @Akina

Comment: But implementation... I do not remember the implementation which have both proper FK system and non-redundant data.

Comment: A relational table? Is it like a parents table relating to children table? If yes it's simple, create a relational table with the FK to both tables. The constraint you are looking for is a bit more complicated and I don't believe there's something in the relational model can achieve it. But it can be easily done if you create some kind of computed hash field and put a unique index on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can not be solved with the relational model, but, as @jean says in the comments, we can calculate a hash of the objects that make up the set of objects and form a field with restriction of uniqueness.